# Find XML file in Android ODK/Open Data Kit-Collect app

Tags: android, odk

I have build a test survey on http://build.opendatakit.org/,
which I then exported to a XML-file.

I installed the app `ODK Collect` on my Android tablet,
and used the app `Terminal Emulator` to put the XML-file on the tablet with:

```
sudo root
cd /sdcard/odk/forms
curl http://www.<domainname>.nl/surveys/Test.xml > Test.xml
```

So the XML-file is now in the forms folder of `ODK Collect`,
but how can I open it now in ODK Collect?

I can't see it when I press the `Get Blank Form` button, how come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form should show up if you click **"Fill Blank Form"** i.e. this shows all available forms already on your device.

**"Get Blank Form"** is used to download new forms from Aggregate i.e. it shows all forms you could potentially download, which would then show in "Fill Blank Form" if the forms download successfully.